# Run Angular change detection only once and stop detecting changes for that component

Tags: angular, typescript, performance, angular2-changedetection, angular-changedetection

I need to detect changes in angular only once when the component is loaded or when route has changed and i want to stop detecting changes after that.

Actually I need to show and hide functionality depending on user role. So i have many `*ngIf` in a single html template but i need to check `*ngIf` condition only once when the template is loaded first time and stop detecting changes after that because it is affecting performance.

I want the page to be like static after single time change detection.

For example :

```
       <li *ngIf="doesHavePermission('templateName')">
       </li>
```

should check once but what I am seeing is that it is checking the change many times for single `*ngIf` and I have many `*ngIf` like this:

I found `markForCheck()` 
 and `detach()` in this angular document https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef.

> But what they are doing is that they are either allowing all change
>   detection or none at all,

And I need to detect changes only once and stop after that.

Can we do this single time change detection in angular?

Or is there a better way to handle the scenerio?

Comment: I recommend reading this article: https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4, which will give you a nice overview of what's possible with the default & onPush strategies. Unfortunately if you are seeing CD related performance issues it usually means your components are written poorly, or you are dealing with large quantities of real-time data. OnPush is a performance tweak that should be used carefully where needed.

Answer (score 5):

When you use a function call inside of `*ngIf` then angular calls this function every time when change detection occurs. It doesn't matter if this changeDetection is triggered outside or inside your component, but angular cannot know if the return value of the function has changed before it has called this function.

So it is not a good approach to use function calls inside `*ngIf` in general.

Alternatives:

Use normal attributes inside your component:

```
instead of 
<div *ngIf="checkCondition()"></div>

use this

<div *ngIf="condition"></div>

@Component(...)
class MyComponent {
 condition= false;

 checkCondition() {
  if(something) {
   this.condition = true;
  }
 }
}
```

With this approach you can handle better when a condition has changed and call the function manually. Instead of just use an attribute you can also use a map:

```
@Component(...) 
class MyComponent{
  conditions: { [key: string]: boolean }

  ngOnInit() {
   condition = {
    template1: true,
    template2: false
   }
  }
}

<div *ngIf="conditions['template1']"></div>
```

In combination with `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` you can minimize the changedetection as `onPush` only triggers change detection when input params has changed. It basically means that change detection from a parent does not trigger change detection of a child.

If you combine these two approaches you should get minimum changedetection:

```
@Component({
...
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
}) 
    class MyComponent{
      @Input() conditions: { [key: string]: boolean }
}
```

Here is a good article for further reading: https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496

Comment: I understood that this is a good approach and it is appreciated but what if i have to run some logic in order to decide true or false for *ngIf ?

Comment: either you run this logic inside ngOnInit and build up your map or in your parent component and pass it down via `@Input`

Comment: So I have a string and i need to check if a specific character is present at a specific index in that string based on the different functionality. So neither can i calculate it in parent and nor in ngOnInit  because it needs to be calculated dynamically as it is dependent on specific functionality. So what do u suggest for this ?

Comment: Calculating something during runtime is dynamic per se. There must be some point where you have all parameters to calculate your condition and normally it is before you render elements based on that condition, so calculating this in parent or ngOnint is the normal way to handle this. In your case I don't know what your requirement is and I don't know your application. Maybe you can provide a stackblitz?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `detach` method for `ChangeDetectorRef` injector to remove current component from Change Detection cycle.
You can always call `reattach` method or manually call `detectChanges` to make the quickly run through the changes.

As for me it's the most reliable way.

But pay attention that it always will turn off change detection for all children!